# Elasticsearch or term combined with date range

Tags: date, elasticsearch, range

I'm trying to query my index with an OR statement which includes a range, to do this I constructed the following query (with help from the documentation):

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "size": 50,
    "filter": {
        "or": [{
            "term": {
                "fromPlace": "liverpool"
            },
            "range" : {
                "query" : {
                    "gte": "01/01/2012",
                    "lte": "2013",
                    "format": "dd/MM/yyyy||yyyy"
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

This, however, gives me a "query malformed, no field after start_object" error. The complete error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "query_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[_na] query malformed, no field after start_object",
        "index": "quote-lanes2",
        "line": 13,
        "col": 15
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "quote-lanes2",
        "node": "opqibf4zRxOXTHz0QIAaeA",
        "reason": {
          "type": "query_parsing_exception",
          "reason": "[_na] query malformed, no field after start_object",
          "index": "quote-lanes2",
          "line": 13,
          "col": 15
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Any suggestions? Or an elaboration on the documentation?
Thanks in advance guys!

### EDIT:

So the query was fixed thanks to [@or-weinberger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407943/or-weinberger), but it doesn't actually filter on the date. I changed "query" to "validFrom" so that my query looks like:

```
{
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "or": [
          {
            "term": {
              "fromPlace": "liverpool"
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "validFrom": {
                "gte": "2017-03-22T08:43:11",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The GTE is obviously in the future and shouldn't match a document with the following value (yet it does):
[image]

My date fields are correctly mapped as date fields:
[image]

Ideally I'd want to filter only on the "yyyy/mm/dddd" part.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is indeed malformed, the filter should be under a `bool` element which should be under the `query` element. Also, when using `or`/`and` you should create separate objects for each filter element (range/term etc..) for example:

```
{
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "or": [
          {
            "term": {
              "fromPlace": "liverpool"
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "query": {
                "gte": "01/01/2012",
                "lte": "2013",
                "format": "dd/MM/yyyy||yyyy"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of the bool thing :)

Comment: So if I want the range to apply on the field "validFrom" I change "query" to "validFrom" right? This yields 0 results, possible because my date format is different right? I got "2015-07-22T08:43:11" I tried setting the format option to yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt but that didn't work. the tt is invalid apparantly.  I then tried changing it to: "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" but that doesn't seem to actually apply the filter.

Comment: So I tried:  "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis" which seems to work but somehow "gte": "2017-03-22T08:43:11" also matches    "validFrom": "2015-07-22T08:43:11" .... mmmm

Comment: Is the field `validFrom` mapped as `date`? Please check by going to the `/_mapping` endpoint.

Comment: Yes it is, let me put some extra info (+ screens) on the initial question

Comment: Done, I added some relevant info the the main question.

Comment: Can you show the returned document? Remember that you've placed an `or` condition meaning that the matched document can also match only on `fromPlace: "liverpool"`.

Comment: Well.... nominate me for the lemming award..... lols I indeed didn't remember that or statement.... :) thanks mate!

Comment: Glad I could help!